# Redux saga won't trigger two async calls simultaneously

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I am trying to use redux saga to make the async calls simultaneously as I load the page... but only the loadPositions() is being called. anyone have an idea why? I think it has to do with a race condition. Please correct me.

```
const fetchPositions = () => {
  return fetch(POSITIONS_API_ENDPOINT).then(function (response) {
    return response.json().then(function (results) {
      return results.map(function (p) {
        return {
          position: p.position,
          platformId: p.platform_id
        }
      })
    })
  })
};

const fetchBanners = () => {
  return fetch(BANNER_API_ENDPOINT).then(function (response) {
    return response.json().then(function (results) {
      return results.map(function (p) {
        console.log(p)
        return {
          banner_id: p.banner_id,
          type: p.image.type,
          width: p.image.width
        }
      })
    })
  })
};


export function* loadBanners() {
  try {
    const banners = yield call(fetchBanners);
    yield put({type: "BANNERS_LOADED", banners})
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({type: "BANNERS_LOAD_FAILURE", error: error})
  }
}

export function* loadPositions() {
  try {
    const positions = yield call(fetchPositions);
    yield put({type: "POSITIONS_LOADED", positions})
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({type: "POSITION_LOAD_FAILURE", error: error})
  }
}


export function* rootSaga() {
  yield [
    loadBanners(),
    loadPositions()
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Start the initial parallel loading by firing the `ON_LOAD_START` action
- Make all your requests in parallel using the `yield []` syntax and fire the appropriate actions with result data.

Root saga, compose all of your sagas:

```or-tag
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield fork(watchOnLoad);
}
```

Watcher saga, waits for action `ON_LOAD_START` before kicking of the worker saga:

```or-tag
function* watchOnLoad() {
  // takeLatest will not start onLoad until an action with type
  // ON_LOAD_START has been fired.
  yield* takeLatest("ON_LOAD_START", onLoad);
}
```

Worker saga, actually makes all the requests in parallel and fires the success or error actions with relevant result data:

```or-tag
export function* onLoad() {
  try {
    const [banners, positions]  = yield [
      call(fetchBanners),
      call(fetchPositions)
    ]
    yield put({type: "ON_LOAD_SUCCESS", banners, positions})
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({type: "ON_LOAD_ERROR", error})
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for ur answer. I will surely test ur example when i get home. In the mean time could u explain why it needs to fire up an action first. Is it just becuz?

Comment: It's not necessary but it's good to be able to control when the requests should start firing.